# Train Tensorflow Model in Google Cloud ML Engine in Python

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

can i train a Tensorflow Model in Google cloud machine learning Engine in python without using the commande Line :

```
     `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
          --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
          --runtime-version 1.2 \
          --module-name trainer.task \
          --package-path trainer/ \
          --region $REGION \ `
```

i aim to run the task from my python script

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `gcloud ml-engine` is just the CLI to the CloudML Engine REST API. The API documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create). Sample code can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-jobs#formatting_your_configuration_parameters); click on the Python tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API or libraries of different languages written over the REST API.

Here is the Google API PHP client service [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/CloudMachineLearningEngine/Resource). You can refer to github.com/boaloysius/google-ml-engine-rest.

Here is the reference to https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-guide.